# Crystal report export cause not responding

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I built a desktop application using VB.NET on Visual Studio 2012. I use Crystal Report to show the report. But when user generated the report and try to export into another file (excel,etc), it always cause my application "Not responding" and closing the application.

Is this memory problem or I have to install something else?

my code to load report in reportviewer controller

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("id-ID")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "Rp "
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-"
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Dim PeriodeAwal As DateTime
    Dim PeriodeAkhir As DateTime

    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        PeriodeAwal = New DateTime(frmJenisLaporan.dtpAwal.Value.Year, frmJenisLaporan.dtpAwal.Value.Month, frmJenisLaporan.dtpAwal.Value.Day)
        PeriodeAkhir = New DateTime(frmJenisLaporan.dtpAkhir.Value.Year, frmJenisLaporan.dtpAkhir.Value.Month, frmJenisLaporan.dtpAkhir.Value.Day)
    End If

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

    Dim t As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("Transaksi")
    Dim r As DataRow
    t.Columns.Add("IDHORDER", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("TANGGAL", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    t.Columns.Add("NOINVOICE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("MEJA", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("Diskon", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("TotalBersih", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("PEMBAYARAN", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("KEMBALIAN", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("JENISORDER", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("CREATEDBY", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("PAX", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("NAMA", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("IDDORDER", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("IDMENU", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("QTY", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("HARGASAATORDER", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("SUBTOTAL", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("NAMAMENU", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("NAMARESTORAN", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("REVISIORNOT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("SERVICECHARGE", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("LOGOLOCATION", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("PAJAK", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    t.Columns.Add("ALASANDISKON", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("DISKONBY", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("CUSTOMERNAME", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("GETPOIN", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("CUSTOMERTOTALPOIN", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    t.Columns.Add("DISKONEXTRA", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))

    Dim counterJumlahPorsi As Integer = 0
    Dim TotalNominal As Decimal = 0

    'ambil data transaksi
    'cmdtxt = "SELECT H.IDHORDER, H.TANGGAL, H.NOINVOICE, H.MEJA, H.TOTAL, H.DISKON, H.TOTALBERSIH, H.PEMBAYARAN, H.KEMBALIAN, H.JENISORDER, H.CREATEDBY, H.PAX, H.NAMA, D.IDDORDER, D.IDMENU, D.QTY, D.HARGASAATORDER, D.SUBTOTAL, M.NAMAMENU, H.SERVICECHARGE,H.PAJAK,H.ALASANDISKON,H.DISKONBY FROM HORDER AS H, DORDER AS D, MENU AS M WHERE (((M.IDMENU)=[D].[IDMENU]) AND ((D.IDHORDER)=[H].[IDHORDER])) AND COMPLETED=True AND KEEPRECORD=True"
    cmdtxt = "SELECT H.IDHORDER, H.TANGGAL, H.NOINVOICE, H.MEJA, H.TOTAL, H.DISKON, H.TOTALBERSIH, H.PEMBAYARAN, H.KEMBALIAN, H.JENISORDER, H.CREATEDBY, H.PAX, H.NAMA, D.IDDORDER, D.IDMENU, D.QTY, D.HARGASAATORDER, D.SUBTOTAL, M.NAMAMENU, H.SERVICECHARGE,H.PAJAK,H.ALASANDISKON,H.DISKONBY, H.GETPOIN, IIF(H.IDCUSTOMER=0,'Non Member',C.NAMACUSTOMER) AS NAMACUSTOMER,H.DISKONEXTRA FROM ((HORDER AS H INNER JOIN DORDER AS D ON D.IDHORDER=H.IDHORDER) INNER JOIN MENU AS M ON M.IDMENU=D.IDMENU) LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER AS C ON C.IDCUSTOMER=H.IDCUSTOMER WHERE H.COMPLETED=TRUE AND H.KEEPRECORD=TRUE"
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DAY(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Day & " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        'cmdtxt &= " AND DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAwal & "')<=H.TANGGAL AND H.TANGGAL<=DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1) & "')"
        cmdtxt &= " AND DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAwal.Month & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Day & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Year & "')<=H.TANGGAL AND H.TANGGAL<=DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Month & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Day & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Year & "')"
    End If
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmdtxt, conn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.Read

            r = t.NewRow()
            r("IDHORDER") = reader.GetValue(0)
            r("TANGGAL") = reader.GetValue(1)
            r("NOINVOICE") = reader.GetValue(2)
            Dim totalMeja() As String = reader.GetValue(3).ToString.Split(",")
            r("MEJA") = totalMeja(0)
            r("Total") = reader.GetValue(4)
            r("Diskon") = reader.GetValue(5)
            r("TotalBersih") = reader.GetValue(6)
            r("PEMBAYARAN") = reader.GetValue(7)
            r("KEMBALIAN") = reader.GetValue(8)
            r("JENISORDER") = reader.GetValue(9)
            r("CREATEDBY") = reader.GetValue(10)
            r("PAX") = reader.GetValue(11)
            r("NAMA") = reader.GetValue(12)
            r("IDDORDER") = reader.GetValue(13)
            r("IDMENU") = reader.GetValue(14)
            r("QTY") = reader.GetValue(15)
            r("HARGASAATORDER") = reader.GetValue(16)
            r("SUBTOTAL") = reader.GetValue(17)
            r("NAMAMENU") = reader.GetValue(18)
            r("NAMARESTORAN") = NamaRestoran
            r("SERVICECHARGE") = reader.GetValue(19)
            r("LOGOLOCATION") = LogoRestoran
            r("PAJAK") = reader.GetValue(20)
            r("ALASANDISKON") = reader.GetValue(21)
            r("DISKONBY") = reader.GetValue(22)
            r("GETPOIN") = reader.GetValue(23)
            r("CUSTOMERNAME") = reader.GetValue(24)
            r("CUSTOMERTOTALPOIN") = 0
            r("DISKONEXTRA") = reader.GetValue(25)
            t.Rows.Add(r)
            counterJumlahPorsi += reader.GetValue(15)
        End While
    End If
    reader.Close()

    'hitung total Nominal Penjualan
    cmdtxt = "SELECT H.TOTALBERSIH FROM HORDER AS H WHERE COMPLETED=True AND KEEPRECORD=True"
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DAY(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Day & " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAwal.Month & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Day & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Year & "')<=H.TANGGAL AND H.TANGGAL<=DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Month & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Day & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Year & "')"
    End If
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmdtxt, conn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        TotalNominal += reader.GetValue(0)
    End While
    reader.Close()

    Dim trptTotal As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("TotalMenuSold")
    Dim rrptTotal As DataRow
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("IDHORDER", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("IDMENU", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("NAMAMENU", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("HARGAJUAL", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("TANGGAL", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("QTY", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("SUBTOTAL", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("TOTALDISKONMEMBER", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("TOTALDISKONEXTRA", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    trptTotal.Columns.Add("TOTALPAJAK", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))

    'ambil total diskon
    Dim varTotalDiskonMember As Decimal = 0
    Dim vartotalDiskonExtra As Decimal = 0
    Dim vartotalPajak As Decimal = 0
    cmdtxt = "SELECT SUM(DISKON) AS 'TOTALDISKONMEMBER',SUM(DISKONEXTRA) AS 'TOTALDISKONEXTRA',SUM(PAJAK) AS 'TOTALPAJAK' FROM HORDER H WHERE  h.COMPLETED=True  AND h.KEEPRECORD=True "
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DAY(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Day & " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAwal.Month & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Day & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Year & "')<=H.TANGGAL AND H.TANGGAL<=DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Month & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Day & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Year & "')"
    End If
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmdtxt, conn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        reader.Read()
        varTotalDiskonMember = reader.GetValue(0)
        vartotalDiskonExtra = reader.GetValue(1)
        vartotalPajak = reader.GetValue(2)
    End If
    reader.Close()

    'ambil total menu terjual
    cmdtxt = "SELECT m.IDMENU, m.NAMAMENU, m.HARGAJUAL, SUM(d.QTY) as 'SOLD' FROM MENU M, HORDER H, DORDER D WHERE  h.COMPLETED=True  AND h.KEEPRECORD=True AND M.IDMENU=D.IDMENU AND H.IDHORDER=D.IDHORDER "
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DAY(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Day & " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND MONTH(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Month & " AND YEAR(H.TANGGAL)=" & Date.Now.Year
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        cmdtxt &= " AND DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAwal.Month & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Day & "-" & PeriodeAwal.Year & "')<=H.TANGGAL AND H.TANGGAL<=DATEVALUE('" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Month & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Day & "-" & PeriodeAkhir.AddDays(1).Year & "')"
    End If
    cmdtxt &= " GROUP BY M.IDMENU,M.NAMAMENU, M.HARGAJUAL"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmdtxt, conn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.Read

            rrptTotal = trptTotal.NewRow()
            rrptTotal("IDHORDER") = -1
            rrptTotal("IDMENU") = reader.GetValue(0)
            rrptTotal("NAMAMENU") = reader.GetValue(1)
            rrptTotal("HARGAJUAL") = reader.GetValue(2)
            rrptTotal("QTY") = reader.GetValue(3)
            rrptTotal("SUBTOTAL") = reader.GetValue(2) * reader.GetValue(3)
            rrptTotal("TOTALDISKONMEMBER") = varTotalDiskonMember
            rrptTotal("TOTALDISKONEXTRA") = vartotalDiskonExtra
            rrptTotal("TOTALPAJAK") = vartotalPajak
            trptTotal.Rows.Add(rrptTotal)
        End While
    End If
    reader.Close()

    Dim rptTotal As New crTotalMenuSold
    rptTotal.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0)) ' define table data for sub report
    rptTotal.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))

    'Isi total porsi terjual per periode laporan
    Dim crParamDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim paramDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParamValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim paramFieldValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    paramFieldValue.Value = counterJumlahPorsi
    crParamDefinitions = rptTotal.Subreports(0).DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    paramDefinition = crParamDefinitions.Item("TotalPorsi")
    crParamValues = paramDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParamValues.Clear()
    crParamValues.Add(paramFieldValue)
    paramDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParamValues)

    paramDefinition = crParamDefinitions.Item("PeriodeLaporan")
    crParamValues = New ParameterValues
    crParamValues = paramDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParamValues.Clear()
    paramFieldValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        paramFieldValue.Value = "HARI INI"
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        paramFieldValue.Value = "BULAN INI"
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        paramFieldValue.Value = PeriodeAwal.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") & " - " & PeriodeAkhir.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
    End If
    crParamValues.Add(paramFieldValue)
    paramDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParamValues)

    paramDefinition = crParamDefinitions.Item("TotalDalamRupiah")
    crParamValues = New ParameterValues
    crParamValues = paramDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParamValues.Clear()
    paramFieldValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
    paramFieldValue.Value = TotalNominal
    crParamValues.Add(paramFieldValue)
    paramDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParamValues)
    '===========================================================


    'Isi total porsi terjual per periode laporan
    Dim crParamDefinitionsrptTotal As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim paramDefinitionrptTotal As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParamValuesrptTotal As ParameterValues
    Dim paramFieldValuerptTotal As ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParamDefinitionsrptTotal = rptTotal.DataDefinition.ParameterFields

    paramDefinitionrptTotal = crParamDefinitionsrptTotal.Item("PeriodeLaporan")
    crParamValuesrptTotal = New ParameterValues
    crParamValuesrptTotal = paramDefinitionrptTotal.CurrentValues
    crParamValuesrptTotal.Clear()
    paramFieldValuerptTotal = New ParameterDiscreteValue
    If lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "today" Then
        paramFieldValuerptTotal.Value = "HARI INI"
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "month" Then
        paramFieldValuerptTotal.Value = "BULAN INI"
    ElseIf lblTodayOrMonth.Text.ToLower = "custom" Then
        paramFieldValuerptTotal.Value = PeriodeAwal.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") & " - " & PeriodeAkhir.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
    End If
    crParamValuesrptTotal.Add(paramFieldValuerptTotal)
    paramDefinitionrptTotal.ApplyCurrentValues(crParamValuesrptTotal)

    '===========================================================

    rptViewer.ReportSource = rptTotal
    rptViewer.Refresh()
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: show your code!

Comment: I don't use any code to export the report, I use default button in report viewer control.

Comment: I use the export in code and it works as expected.